# How can I Find and replace all text that has a style in MS Word 2013 without changing style on line below

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, find-and-replace

I have a MS Word 2013 document with several *headings* that are styled as "Heading 4".  My goal is to replace all text that is styled as "Heading 4" to ###### and style "Heading 5".

I use the following search:
[image]

Which does what I want it to, except it pulls up the line below it styled as "heading 3" onto the same line and therefor it converts my "Heading 3" line also.  I don't want that to happen.  See images below:
Text before find/replace:

[image]

After Replace:

[image]

But this is what I want it to look like (GOAL RESULT):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current command replaces also paragraph mark at the end of the paragraph, so replaced paragraph get merged with the next one.

Use this in replace with box: `#####^p`